# Webix: custom footer datafilter

Tags: javascript, webix

I'm using treetables and I implemented a custom datafilter. I just want to make some operation at the first level of data hierarchy. Do you know how could I make it?

I'll show you some context. In the gif below when I click to open the inside level of data the sum (or avg) changes. It is wrong one time that the high level has this information calculated.

[image]

I just need to put a condition, it is first level make something.

Here is my current code.

```
<script>
webix.ui.datafilter.reports = {
   refresh: function(master, node, column){
      trackCells:false,
      refresh: function(master, node, column){
         var result = 0;
         var tipoDeDados = null;

         master.mapCells(null, column.columnId, null, 1, function(value){

            if (tipoDeDados === null) {
               tipoDeDados = defineTipoDeDados(value);
            }

            valorLimpo = removeCaracteresInvalidos(value);

            result += valorLimpo; // here I think that I need the condition
            return value;
         });

         if (tipoDeDados === "porcentagem") {
            node.firstChild.innerHTML = (result/master.count()).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + '%';
         } else if (tipoDeDados === "moeda") {
            node.firstChild.innerHTML = 'R$ ' + (result).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
         } else if (tipoDeDados === "numerico") {
            node.firstChild.innerHTML = result;
         } else {
            node.firstChild.innerHTML = "";
         }
      },
      render: function(a, b){}
   };
</script>
```

Webix Docs says that I just need to put  trackCells false to avoid reloading data filter, but its not working when I got new data through ajax loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With code below I got the results that I wanted.

```
webix.ui.datafilter.reports = {
   trackCells:false,
   refresh: function(master, node, value){
      var result = 0;
      var numberCellsAtFirstLevel = 0;
      var tipoDeDados = null;

      master.data.each(function(obj) {

         currentValue = obj[value.columnId];

         if (tipoDeDados === null) {
            tipoDeDados = defineTipoDeDados(currentValue);
         }

         valorLimpo = removeCaracteresInvalidos(currentValue);

         if (obj.$level == 1) {
            result += valorLimpo;
            numberCellsAtFirstLevel += 1
         }

         return currentValue;
      });

      if (tipoDeDados === "porcentagem") {
         node.firstChild.innerHTML = (result/numberCellsAtFirstLevel).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + '%';
      } else if (tipoDeDados === "moeda") {
         node.firstChild.innerHTML = 'R$ ' + (result).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
      } else if (tipoDeDados === "numerico") {
         node.firstChild.innerHTML = result;
      } else {
         node.firstChild.innerHTML = "";
      }
   },
   render: function(a, b){}
};
```